# Merge two 2d arrays and sum intersecting elements

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge, sum

I need to sum the values from two arrays where their key paths intersect.  The arrays will have the exact same shape and size.

My sample input arrays:

```
$arr1 = [
    [3206.63, 815.47],
    [5024.71, 803.73],
    [3290.36, 625.02],
];

$arr2 = [
    [3138.87, 819.8],
    [5000.24, 810.87],
    [3221.15, 668.58],
];
```

Desired result:

```
[
    [6345.5, 1635.27],
    [10024.95, 1614.6],
    [6511.51, 1293.6]
]
```

Comment: It might help to show an example of the desired final array. Also, show the code you've attempted using `array_walk` and tell us what specifically went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the first array and use its keys to synchronously access values from the second array.

```
$sums = array();

foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
    $sums[$key][] = $arr1[$key][0] + $arr2[$key][0];
    $sums[$key][] = $arr1[$key][1] + $arr2[$key][1];
}

print_r($sums);
```

Answer (score 0):

In a functional-style script, iterate the rows of both arrays synchronously, then iterate the columns per row and sum those isolated columnar values.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/YDLO5))

```
print_r(
    array_map(
        fn(...$rows) => array_map(
            fn(...$col) => array_sum($col),
            ...$rows
        ),
        $arr1,
        $arr2
    )
);
```

---

For a classic nested loop, copy the first array to the result array (no reason to iterate it), then add the second array's values -- according to their key path -- to the result data.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/HNDiE))

```
$result = $arr1;
foreach ($arr2 as $i => $row) {
    foreach ($row as $k => $v) {
        $result[$i][$k] += $v;
    }
}
print_r($result);
```